# Web method not called from ajax post

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, angularjs, webmethod

I am trying to call a method as web method from ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'LifeStyleManager.aspx/AddSelfEntry',
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: angular.toJson(categories),
                    //data: angular.copy(categories)
```

also tried data as "{'items' : '" + angular.toJson(categories) + "'}"

which is serialized as

```
{
    "items": "[{\"name\":\"Fruits\",\"metrics\":\"cups\",\"entry\":0,\"recommended\":true,\"color\":\"#989898\"},{\"name\":\"Vegetables\",\"metrics\":\"cups\",\"entry\":1,\"recommended\":true,\"color\":\"#37A0BC\"},{\"name\":\"Whole Grains\",\"metrics\":\"cups\",\"entry\":1,\"recommended\":true,\"color\":\"#37A0BC\"},{\"name\":\"Fast Foods\",\"metrics\":\"times\",\"entry\":0,\"recommended\":false,\"color\":\"#989898\"},{\"name\":\"Sweets\",\"metrics\":\"times\",\"entry\":0,\"recommended\":false,\"color\":\"#989898\"},{\"name\":\"Sugary Drinks\",\"metrics\":\"times\",\"entry\":0,\"recommended\":false,\"color\":\"#989898\"}]"
}
```

Here categories is serialized as

```
 [
    {
        "name": "Fruits",
        "metrics": "cups",
        "entry": 0,
        "recommended": true,
        "color": "#989898"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vegetables",
        "metrics": "cups",
        "entry": 1,
        "recommended": true,
        "color": "#37A0BC"
    }
]
```

Webmethod is like:

```
        [WebMethod(true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string AddSelfEntry(List<Entry> items)
        {
```

Here entry is

```
public class Entry
        {
            public string name;
            public string metrics;
            public int entry;
            public bool recommended;
            public string color;

        }
```

I am getting error at console:

[image]

No breakpoint hit at webmethod in debugmode.

**Update**: I am calling ajax from another html page not aspx page where web method sits in code-behind. Is it be the cause?

Please help where I am wrong?

Comment: And what is the error in your server ? Because this console error only said that there is an error on your backend.

Comment: Why are you using `$.ajax` in angular and not `$http`?

Comment: @Apédémak, no hit at web method while debugger is attached.

Comment: @charlietfl, There are some jquery promise framework working over these but there is no problem in that

Comment: If you debug your server side code does the JS even reach your .NET code?

Comment: Also, is it normal that in your code url is `Manager.aspx/AddSelfEntry` and in your screen `LifestyleManager.aspx/AddSelfEntry` ?

Comment: @timothyclifford No hit at webmethod on server, that is the problem. In other words,YES, js don't reach .Net code in debug mode.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Apédémak, route looks a bit off

Comment: @Apédémak, That's same at both places, I changed js code for SO question.

Comment: Are you inside of an ASP.NET Master page by chance?

Comment: Not inside masterpage

Answer (score 1):

What is your jQuery version?

> **type** (default: `'GET'`)
>
> Type: *String*
>
> An alias for `method`.
>
> You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Instead of `method`, try `type: "POST"` in your AJAX.